# Java downloading file: "Connection timed out: connect"

Tags: java, file, url, download, timeout

When I'm downloading file (35MB) using below code. It gives me the output as:

> Connection timed out: connect

Below is my java codes for file downloading process. How can I fix this issue?

```java
//download file
public void download(String url, File destination) throws IOException {
    URL website = new URL(url);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);        
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}

public void parserAction() throws Exception {
    // InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
    File modelFile = new File("en-parser-chunking.bin");

    if (!modelFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Downloading model.");
        download("file://E:/Final Project/Softwares and tools/en-parser-chunking.bin", modelFile);

    }       
    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(modelFile);
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
    for (Parse p : topParses) {
        //p.show();
        getNounPhrases(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of server are you trying to connect to?  Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I'm downloading this file from my hard disk partition to my web application. The uploading task takes too much time and finally it says connection timed out: connect. Is there any way to stop this time out ? or speedup the downloading task ?

Comment: It's a "connection timed out" error, so your problem isn't speed, it's that you can't actually connect to the server.  I think the problem is that you're using a "file" protocol, when it should be http, e.g. http://myserver/en-parser-chunking.bin".

Comment: I'm not clear how to use http for this task. Can you please explain me littlie how to do it in this code ?

Comment: You say you're running a web application, so it should just be a case of changing the URL to where the document is being served by your web server, e.g. "http:..." etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use following codes to set a time out for the connection manually and see which time will be long enough to let the file being uploaded successfully:

```
            String url;            

         try{    
         HttpURLConnection Conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL( url ).openConnection();

                                      Conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                                      Conn.setReadTimeout(2000);

             }
     catch (java.lang.ClassCastException|ConnectException|java.lang.IllegalArgumentException|java.net.MalformedURLException  ex) { }  //catch the possible exception.
     catch (SSLHandshakeException |SocketException | SocketTimeoutException | UnknownHostException ex)
```

Times are in milliseconds by the way.

Comment: I set both the connection timeout and read timeout as 60000 (60 seconds). Still the error Connection Timeout is thrown after around 15 seconds. Where did I go wrong?